# How to build a specific Android cli executable (service.cpp)

Tags: android, c++, build, android-service, android-source

In android, when you open a terminal emulator or connect an adb shell, there is a command `service` that you can execute which allows you to interact with system services to some degree. For my purposes the functionality is too limited though and I would like to expand it a little.

Unfortunately this executable is not documented.

I have located the source code here: [service.cpp](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-11.0.0_r3:frameworks/native/cmds/service/service.cpp)

There is also a file called [Android.bp](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-11.0.0_r3:frameworks/native/cmds/service/Android.bp) in the same directory with the following content:

```
cc_binary {
    name: "service",

    srcs: ["service.cpp"],

    shared_libs: [
        "libcutils",
        "libutils",
        "libbinder",
    ],

    cflags: [
        "-DXP_UNIX",
        "-Wall",
        "-Werror",
    ],
}

cc_binary {
    name: "vndservice",

    proprietary: true,
    srcs: ["service.cpp"],

    shared_libs: [
        "libcutils",
        "libutils",
        "libbinder",
    ],

    cflags: [
        "-DXP_UNIX",
        "-DVENDORSERVICES",
        "-Wall",
        "-Werror",
    ],
}
```

Those cflags look like g++ flags to me. I don't really know g++, but after a lot of trial and error I ended up with this:

```
# Download required source code
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/superproject
cd superproject
git submodule init
git submodule update frameworks/native
git submodule update system/libbase
git submodule update system/core
git submodule update system/logging
# Set required include directories in CPATH
export CPATH="./frameworks/native/include:./system/libbase/include:./system/core/libcutils/include:./system/core/libutils/include:./system/logging/liblog/include:./system/core/libsystem/include:./frameworks/native/libs/binder/include"
# Build
g++ -DXP_UNIX -Wall -Werror -o service ./frameworks/native/cmds/service/service.cpp
```

Unfortunately I get a massive amount of errors:
https://pastebin.com/fnu7LJLU

My G++ version is:
`g++ (GCC) 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2)`

Any ideas why this is failing?

Comment: That g++ is for your host platform, right? If your target platform is ARM, you need a matching cross-compiler / toolchain. The easiest way to set this up, including the toolchain and all the dependencies of the file you want to compile, would be to checkout the full AOSP tree (https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading) and then use the Android build scripts for building that module.

Comment: For reference, here is the full compiler invocation for service.cpp from my Android 8 build log: https://pastebin.com/raw/jtdQGH5L But as I said, I don't think doing this manually would be very productive.

Comment: I've tried checking out all the source code at first, but I don't have enough disk space. Checking out the source and building it apparently requires at least 400GB of free disk space. I need something more reasonable because otherwise I can't properly integrate it into free CI systems and make it accessible to anyone. I didn't think about the architecture being an issue, thanks for pointing that out. I tried building it on my phone directly now, but I still get a lot of errors: https://pastebin.com/xQfeM4rJ

Comment: I've also tried to compile it with clang++ on my device, so that I can copy paste your command, but no success so far.

Comment: Got clang++ to work on my phone and PC, but I get a `fatal error: 'map' file not found` indicating that it can't find the standard headers. Kinda weird as a simple `clang++ test.cpp -o test` with a map include works just fine.

Comment: I had to remove `-nostdlibinc` from your command. Now I get these 20 errors: https://pastebin.com/QCLzRFcj This is the command I ran: https://pastebin.com/kwsbFC8r

Comment: The last one (about `std::optional`) is about the C++ standard version. Android 8 uses C++14 (see the `-std=gnu++14` in the command I posted). `std::optional` is C++17. Either adapt that flag, or build an older version of ``service.cpp``. The other  could be a 32bit vs 64bit issue.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to compile like this now `clang++ -c -target x86_64-linux-android -std=gnu++17 -o ./service frameworks/native/cmds/service/service.cpp`! But of course I need to compile this for `aarch64-linux-android`. When I try to do that on my phone I still get 7 errors: https://pastebin.com/n6zhFrh3 All of them starting with`error: use of undeclared identifier 'android_fdsan_*`

Comment: I figured it out! I was missing the `bionic` submodule and `./bionic/libc/include` in my CPATH. Then I can finally compile it with `clang++ -c -target aarch64-linux-android -std=gnu++17 -o ./service frameworks/native/cmds/service/service.cpp` (on my phone in Termux). :) Thank you so much for all your help again. Maybe you can add an actual answer to this question so that I can accept it.

Comment: This is much easier to build in android 11, just add "host_supported: true" to the cc_binary definition. And then "mmm frameworks/native/cmds/service".

Comment: Where do I add that an where does the mmm binary come from?